# How to Get client (user) date time in XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I am converting XML to HTML using XSLT and the converted html is available in application to provide a report.

User may open the HTML from any timezone so based on respective zone I have to show the datetime in report?

How its possible let me know your suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use client-side javascript? Your question is not entirely clear.

Answer (score 1):

If different people are to see the same HTML in different ways, then you need to do something clever in the HTML, typically with Javascript.

Once you have worked out what HTML you want to generate, producing it using XSLT should be easy.

On the other hand, if you want to generate different HTML for different users, then you will need a parameter to the stylesheet that supplies the relevant information, e.g. timezone. Declaring a parameter using xsl:param is straightforward; the way you supply a value for the parameter depends on your processing environment and API.